# How to disable csrf for a specific route in Sails v1

Tags: node.js, sails.js, csrf

In previous versions it was possible to disable csrf for specific routes using:

```
module.exports.csrf = {
  "routesDisabled": "/webhooks/testhook,/webhooks/anotherhook"
}
```

Is there a new way to do that or should I make a small hack in the controller for auto-generate a csrf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, now it is done in `/routes.js` like this:

```
'PUT   /webhooks/testhook':                        { action: 'entrance/testhook', csrf: false},
```

Comment: do you know how to do the same but for routes defined like 'POST /notifications':     'NotificationsController.log' ?

Comment: Where was this documented? How did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Great! Official updated documentation states you can turn CSRF protection on or off on a per-route basis by adding csrf: true or csrf: false to any route in your config/routes.js file.

More info: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/csrf